# ASP.NET Find Control with only part of the UniqueID

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

So I have a situation where we are trying to reduce the page size. My job is to remove as much of the uniqueID's in the markup as possible.

This is where I'm having a problem: I have a `value` which is `"innerContent$wizard$myTextBox"` and its `UniqueID` is `ctl00$ctl00$content$innerContent$wizard$myTextBox`. I have a call on the page `page.FindControl(value)` which returns null because I only have half the `UniqueID`

So my question is: How can I use `FindControl()` with only half the `UniqueID`? I'm certain that the `value` is unique for the page. (i.e there is no other `UniqueID` ending with this value.)

Answer (score 0):

Which half do you get?

If you are using asp.net 4.0, set the ClientIDMode="Static"

[Link regarding ClientIDMode](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article838-aspnet-40-manipulate-clientid-using-clientidmode-.aspx)

[Here is another one that talks about Predictable, but briefly goes over others](http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/understanding-clientidmodepredictable.html)

Comment: I have the last half. As it shows in the example I set. The static id of my control won't work in the `page.FindControl()` otherwise i could split the value I'm getting and use the last section.

Comment: Explain reason for downvoting?

Comment: It is not useful. I was asking how can i find a control with only half its UniqueID how does changing the ClientIDMode to static help?

Comment: I mentioned that because you are using asp.net 4.0 according to tags you put for your question and you can control.  If you set the ClientIdMode to Static for the controls, you can control how asp.net renders the id of the control on the client side.  I will update my post with a link.

Comment: I am using ClientIDMode and that is what is giving me the issue. I don't want to change the clientID its fine. What i'm having trouble with is that the FindControl function cannot find a control with only the last half of the UniqueID. I need a way around this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you were using ClientIDMode.  Which half of the ID are you getting?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have to use the Page's find control method? Usually you would use the findcontrol method of the parent control or naming contained and pass the Id in the mark up rather than the uniqueId.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't write that code and that is just where the call is. I can't get to the naming container from there that I know of.

Comment: You can always get to control inside of page, it may take a bit of work but should not have a problem accessing it.

Comment: I don't understand how? You haven't given any information about what you mean.